# Adding two numbers that are represented as graphs

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to solve the this problem on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/
My general strategy is:

1. add the first digits from each list
2. keep adding digits until one node (or both) is at the last element
3. keep adding from the list that has more elements
4. return value

One test I ran was with `l1 = [1,8,6]` and `l2 = [1,2,3]`. My answer was `[0,0,0]` and the correct answer was `[2,0,0,1]`.

I have added comments to improve readability.

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* public class ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode next;
*     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
* }
*/
public class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        int carry = 0;
        int ii = l1.val + l2.val;
        ListNode nd;
        if (ii >= 10){ // adding the first digits
            carry = ii / 10;
            nd = new ListNode(ii%10);
        } else {
            nd = new ListNode(ii);
        }
        ListNode lst = nd;
        // keep adding corresponding digits until one of the lists is about to end
        while (l1.next != null && l2.next != null){ 
            l1 = l1.next;
            l2 = l2.next;
            int sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
            if (sum >= 10){
                carry = sum/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
            else {
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum);
                nd = nd.next;
                carry = 0;
            }
        }

        if (l1.next == null && l2.next != null){
            // adding the last digit of l1 to the corresponding l2 digit
            int sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
            if (sum >= 10){
                carry = sum/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
            else {
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
            l2 = l2.next;
            while (l2.next != null){
                int sum1 = l2.val + carry;
                if (sum1 >= 10){
                    carry = sum1/10;
                    nd.next = new ListNode(sum1%10);
                    nd = nd.next;
                } else {
                    carry = 0;
                    nd.next = new ListNode(sum1);
                    nd = nd.next;
                }
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            int neww = l2.val + carry;
            if (neww >= 10){ // adding last digit to total sum
                carry = neww/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(neww%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            } else {
                carry = 0;
                nd.next = new ListNode(neww);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
        }
        else if (l2.next == null && l1.next != null) {
            int sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
            if (sum >= 10){
                carry = sum/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
            else {
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum);
                nd = nd.next;
                carry = 0;
            }
            l1 = l1.next;
            while (l1.next != null){
                int sum2 = l1.val + carry;
                if (sum2 >= 10){
                    carry = sum2/10;
                    nd.next = new ListNode(sum2%10);
                    nd = nd.next;
                } else {
                    carry = 0;
                    nd.next = new ListNode(sum2);
                    nd = nd.next;
                }
                l1 = l1.next;
            }
            int neww = l1.val + carry;
            if (neww >= 10){
                carry = neww/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(neww%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            } else {
                carry = 0;
                nd.next = new ListNode(neww);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
        }
        else { // both lists have same size
            int sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
            if (sum >= 10){
                carry = sum/10;
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum%10);
                nd = nd.next;
            }
            else {
                nd.next = new ListNode(sum);
                nd = nd.next;
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        return lst.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us how addTwoNumbers() is called along with the linked list values

Comment: I do not know how the method is called, the website calls it by itself. It just gives us the structure of the ListNode class, which is in the first comment block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public List<Integer> solution(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    if (a.length != b.length)
        throw new AssertionError();

    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>(a.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result.add(a.get(i) + b.get(i));
    } 
    return result;
}
```